# Pre-build command-line syntax in Flash-Develop. How to properly reference a class?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flashdevelop, starling-framework

this is probably really simple for you, but I just don't get it (googling wasn't much of a help this time).

I'd like to create a preloader for my (Starling Framework) game, and in order to do so I need to create a second frame in my Preloader.as, which contains my MainClass in it, and I want to accomplish this via a Pre-build command-line. I'm told it works like this: "-frame frameLabel MainClass" (but unfortunately it gives me a lot of headaches).

My folder structure looks like this:
(Preloader: ) GameFolder -> project_web -> src -> Preloader.as
(MainClass: ) GameFolder -> src_game -> MainClass.as

They are of course all part of the same FlashDevelop-project, and therefore I can easily import MainClass.as in the code via "import MainClass", unfortunately not so via command-lines.

I don't understand how to properly setup the path to MainClass.as in this command-line-syntax. (MainClass.as isn't subcategorized, just "package { ... }")

'-frame two MainClass' -> doesn't work, "Exception: File not found" (roughly translated)
'-frame two src_game.MainClass' -> "Exception: File not found"
'-frame two ....\src_game\MainClass.as' -> "Exception: File not found"
(... and many more attempts with "Exception: File not found" ...)

Please, how is it done correctly?

Comment: Okay, finally got it. It was a misunderstanding between me and FlashDevelop. Flash Develops "Pre-Build Command-Line" was the wrong place to put said command-line. The right place is "Additional compiler arguments"!

Answer (score 0):

You can try and implement it in the classic way using [Loader](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Loader.html). Compile your main application to SWF file and load it in run time.

Another way is to use the preloader class from [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4LHezCo0niI) tutorial.

Comment: This does not work with Starling, unfortunately :( .